Problem with Capacitive Feedback Amplifier
I am building two capacitive feedback amplifiers whose schematics are shown in the figure below. The left amplifier has one input dc grounded and the other input connected to an input signal. The right amplifier accepts a differential input signals. CFs for the left amplifier is half the size of those for the right amplifier to ensure equal signal swings for the two amplifiers. Both amplifiers have a capacitive load CL and the inputs (VI,VIP,VIN) are ideal voltage sources.
When I ran the transient simulation, I noticed that the left amplifier had different dc voltages for its outputs (VOP_1 and VON_1), while the right amplifier had the same dc voltages for its outputs (VOP_2 and VON_2).
I'm not sure as to why this happened. Please give me some help on this issue.

This is the schematic from simulation (Case Left). Port VIP is connected to input signal source (VI) and Port VIN to DC Ground as described above.

This is the connection.

This is the schematic from simulation (Case Right). Port VIP and VIN are connected to differential input signals VIP and VIN respectively.

This is the connection.

This is the simulation result.

Simulation Update (Using R0, R1 = 100K)
The capacitors and resistors are ideal components

This is the simulation result (top = overall view, bottom = zoomed-in view). From the look of it, there is still a shift in output dc levels.


Simulation Update (Measure output common-mode voltage)
From the simulation, SE case has way larger output common-mode voltage and the waveform looks a bit distorted. DM case also has output common-mode voltage but with smaller levels.


No DC path ... So, outputs are "shifting.

Please, what polarity does Vcm have? CM recalls common mode but I don't see a relationship. Also you need to correct the drawing since C1 seems to be shorted.

@Antonio51 Wouldn’t outputs be fixed by the common-mode feedback circuit?

@Franc Vcm is half the supply rails which is Vdd/2. Sorry about the drawing. CI isn’t shorted

To answer this question we need to know what loads and sources were attached to the capacitors

@VoltageSpike I have included the loads for the amplifiers. The sources VIP, VIN, VI are ideal voltage sources.

Please update the schematic, if wild be good if you could provide the one from your simulation

@VoltageSpike I have update the post :)

You might try it with R1 and R0 values of around 100K, and see if it improves it.  5M will be sensitive to even the smallest bias current, and may be within the leakage specs of the caps as well, if you're not using ideal components in the sim.

The issue could be that in the SE case, half of your input signal is a common-mode component, potentially messing with your CMFB. I suspect if you plot the CM component at the output (VOP1 + VOP2) / 2, you would see a sinusoid for the SE amplifier while DM would return zero.

@CristobolPolychronopolis I have updated the simulation

@a360pilot I have updated the simulation
